# Grails Spring Security session.user is null

Tags: grails, spring-security

In a previous application, we were able to access the `session.user.PROPERTY` from our controllers which we were using annotation for the security. In a new application, we decided to use the `RequestMap` for storing the rules. When checking for a value from the user domain class in the controller, we get an `NullPointerException` error stating that `session.user` is a null object.

In the previous application it was convenient to access `session.user.WHATEVER` and have access to user info directly from the session without having to query the user info with the `principal.id`.

Comment: But in somewhere, `e.g. in filters` who have to do `String userName = springSecurityService?.principal?.username` or `session.user = springSecurityService?.principal` right

Comment: It's a really bad idea to store the user in the session like this. The plugin was designed to make it convenient to access user information without hacks like this. Get out of the habit of polluting the session with junk that shouldn't be there - if you do end up having a lot of traffic, you'll be glad you kept the sessions small. Use the Spring Security `principal` where possible, and you can always create a custom `UserDetailsService` to add extra data to the `principal` (e.g. name, telephone #, etc.) since the `GrailsUser` instance (or your subclass) is the `principal`

Comment: @BurtBeckwith is there an example of how to do that based on your suggestion?

Comment: It has its own chapter in the docs.

Comment: This information can be found here: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityService

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to retrieve the currently logged-in user, the easiest way to do this is to use the `springSecurityService` bean, e.g.

```
class MyController {

  def springSecurityService

  def myAction() {
    def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
  }
}
```